# Which year has the maximum number of people alive

Tags: python

Given birth years and death years for people in a list (birth1, death1, birth2, death2...) which year has the maximum number of people alive.

Am I thinking about how to solve this the correct way? I'm not a coder and am just having fun with the problem. Here is my attempt at a solution.

```
list1 = [1900, 1990, 1950, 1997, 1937, 1961, 1912, 1919, 1927, 1981]

initial_year = 0
alive = 0
for i in range(1900,2000):
    count = len(list1)/2
    for j in list1:
        if j%2 == 1 and j<=i:
            count = count - 1
            if count>alive:
                initial_year = i
                alive = count

return initial_year
```

Comment: Please don't post code in screenshots. Instead, [edit] your post, copy-paste your code, select it, and press Ctrl+K

Comment: I did what you suggested. Not sure it made a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're just trying to solve it for fun, here's an inefficient but simple algorithm: split the problem into two parts

1. for each year, determine how many people are alive that year
2. find the year with the highest number of people alive

Answer (score 0):

The naive implementation looks like:

```
lst = [1900, 1990, 1950, 1997, 1937, 1961, 1912, 1919, 1927, 1981]

birth_years = lst[0::2]
# extended slice notation means: start with the first element, end with the 
# last element, and take every second element in between
death_years = lst[1::2]
# start with the second, end with the last, and take every second

alive = 0
max_alive = (0, None)  # (num_alive, year)

for year in range(min(birth_years), max(death_years)+1):
    alive += birth_years.count(year)
    alive -= birth_years.count(year)
    if alive > max_alive[0]:
        max_alive = (alive, year)
```

A more robust implementation might look more like:

```
import collections

Person = collections.namedtuple("Person", "born died")
# define a structure with two attributes: "born" and "died"

people = [Person(born, died) for born, died in zip(lst[0::2], lst[1::2])]
# build a list of people

years = {y: sum(1 for p in people if p.born <= y <= p.died)
         for y in range(min(lst), max(lst)+1)}
# use a dictionary comprehension to see how many people are alive in each year

result = max(years, key=lambda k: years[k])
# use the max built-in with a key function to get the resulting year
```

My gut instinct tells me that the naive implementation will be *much* faster for small lists, but the robust implementation might win out in large lists and certainly for large year ranges. `list.count` is O(n), and has to run over both half-lists. The dict comprehension is also O(n), but only has to run on half the list.

Comment: Ah, this is much better. I made the bad initial assumption that everyone would start of by being alive in each year.

Answer (score 0):

**In JavaScript**

```
function writeOutput(inputArray) {


let n = inputArray.length;
let births = [];
let deaths = [];
let alive = 1;
let max_alive = 1;
let ix = 1;
let j = 0;


for ( i=0; i<inputArray.length ; i++){
    if ((i+2)%2 == 0){
        births.push(inputArray[i]);
    } else {
        deaths.push(inputArray[i]);
    }
}

let birthsSorted = births.sort();
let deathsSorted = deaths.sort();
let year = birthsSorted[0];
while (ix < n && j < n ){
    if (birthsSorted[ix] <= deathsSorted[ix]){
        alive += 1;
        if(alive > max_alive){
            max_alive = alive;
            year = birthsSorted[ix]
        }
        ix++;
        console.log(alive)
    } else {
        alive = alive - 1;
        j++;
    }
}


return year;   }
```